# How to use Code Igniter classes in your Non MVC project?

Tags: php, codeigniter, class

I have been looking for a way to use external classes with my PHP API. Since it is a single page and I don't need MVC architecture , I don't want to use controllers, views etc in it. BUT I am still interested in using CI classes to perform operations e.g database operations, active records, caching etc .

I would appreciate if anybody could help me with an example or if possible, just post a link to tutorial so that I could get an idea how can I achieve this ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure with CI, but it seems you're after something similar to composer (https://getcomposer.org/), which uses packagist (https://packagist.org/). If CI has its classes available on packagist, then you would be able to install them in any project (MVC or not).

Comment: have you tried including the class files in your project???

Comment: Why not just use codeigniter as is with 1 controller and no views? Controllers don't have to return a view, and code igniter is pretty light, so I wouldn't worry about its footprint in terms of file size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how that would work but try for example this:

1. get and include what you need

   require_once( BASEPATH .'database/DB'. EXT );

   $db =& DB();
2. Use that instance for what you neeed...

   $variabla = $db->get('some_table')->result_array();

Comment: Sorry.i tried the method but it is giving me error.